# pandas: keep top x% of dataframe by value_counts of specific column

Tags: python, pandas

```
autos["brand"].value_counts(normalize=True)
```

Outputs the following:

```
volkswagen       0.211
bmw              0.126
mercedes_benz    0.109
audi             0.099
opel             0.090
ford             0.059
renault          0.038
peugeot          0.028
fiat             0.021
skoda            0.019
seat             0.018
smart            0.017
toyota           0.015
mazda            0.015
citroen          0.014
nissan           0.014
hyundai          0.011
mini             0.011
volvo            0.009
kia              0.008
sonstige_autos   0.007
honda            0.007
mitsubishi       0.007
porsche          0.007
chevrolet        0.006
alfa_romeo       0.006
suzuki           0.006
Name: brand, dtype: float64
```

I want the fastest/most-efficient way to select brands whose normalized value counts are above 3% (0.03).

I can certainly creates a boolean mask:

```
brands_bool = brand_percentages > 0.03
```

and then apply it to the `df`, but I was wondering if there's a faster/shorter way.

Comment: what about: `autos["brand"].map(autos["brand"].value_counts(normalize=True) > 0.03)`

Comment: `autos['brand'][autos['brand_percentages']>0.03]` ?